# How to update all the values in a BTreeSet?

Tags: collections, module, rust

I have collection which is a field in a struct in some module. I want to update all the values in the collection from another module.

I wrote some code to mimic what I want to achieve. It's shortened a bit, but I think it has all needed parts. There is no struct holding the collection in this code, but imagine this is a getter which returns the collection. I added in comments how I think it should look.

```
pub mod pos {
    use std::cmp::{Ordering, PartialEq};

    #[derive(PartialOrd, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug, Copy, Clone)]
    pub struct Pos {
        pub x: i32,
        pub y: i32,
    }

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    impl Pos {
        pub fn of(x: i32, y: i32) -> Self {
            Self { x, y }
        }

        pub fn offset(&mut self, pos: &Self) -> Self {
            self.x += pos.x;
            self.y += pos.y;

            *self
        }
    }

    impl Ord for Pos {
        fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
            if self.x < other.x {
                Ordering::Less
            } else if self.eq(other) {
                Ordering::Equal
            } else {
                Ordering::Greater
            }
        }
    }
}

mod test {
    use crate::pos::Pos;
    use std::collections::BTreeSet;

    #[test]
    fn test_iterators() {
        let mut data_in_some_strct: BTreeSet<Pos> = BTreeSet::new();

        data_in_some_strct.insert(Pos::of(1, 1));
        data_in_some_strct.insert(Pos::of(2, 2));
        data_in_some_strct.insert(Pos::of(3, 3));
        data_in_some_strct.insert(Pos::of(4, 4));

        // mimic getter call ( get_data(&mut self) -> &BTreeSet<Pos> {...}
        //    let set = data_in_some_strct;   // works, but not a reference
        let set = &data_in_some_strct; // doesn't work, How to adjust code to make it work??

        data_in_some_strct = set
            .into_iter()
            .map(|mut p| p.offset(&Pos::of(1, 0)))
            .inspect(|p| println!("{:?}", *p))
            .collect();

        assert_eq!(data_in_some_strct.contains(&Pos::of(2, 1)), true);
        assert_eq!(data_in_some_strct.contains(&Pos::of(3, 2)), true);
        assert_eq!(data_in_some_strct.contains(&Pos::of(4, 3)), true);
        assert_eq!(data_in_some_strct.contains(&Pos::of(5, 4)), true);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=276b701a244612798b185a444b12d2aa)

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*p` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/lib.rs:56:26
   |
56 |             .map(|mut p| p.offset(&Pos::of(1, 0)))
   |                       -  ^ `p` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
   |                       |
   |                       help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut pos::Pos`
```

I managed to make it work without borrowing, but I would like to make it work with borrowing. I guess there is more then one way to achieve it. Comments to help my Rust [brain dendrites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrite) connect are welcome.

Comment: What led you to use `into_iter` / `map` / `collect` here?

Comment: @Shepmaster Curiosity. I'm learning Rust at moment and I was reading about [Iterrator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) and I'm fan of Java 8+ streams. So tried to do I thought "simple thing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mutate items that are part of a `HashSet` or `BTreeSet` because the *value* of the items determines how they are stored and accessed. If you mutate them then, as [Stargateur mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54697558/493729), you would break the mechanics of the collection. In the case of a `HashSet`, you would change the hash of the item, which determines the location where the data is stored. In the case of a `BTreeSet`, the algorithm is based on how the items are sorted.

You are able to do it by taking ownership because you consume the original set and produce a new, well-formed one. You can't take ownership of a borrowed value because that would leave behind a dangling pointer, which Rust will not let you do.

One possible solution is to temporarily replace the original set with an empty one. Then you can take ownership of its contents, as in your working code, and finally write the newly updated set over the original:

```
let set = std::mem::replace(&mut data_in_some_strct, BTreeSet::new());

data_in_some_strct = set.into_iter()
    .map(|mut p| p.offset(&Pos::of(1,0)))
    .inspect(|p| println!("{:?}", *p))
    .collect();
```

Comment: Is here would be possible to do smth like: get collection (borrow it) > take (remove from collection) each element > update it > insert back to collection updated element. In that case tree wont be broken. I assume hash will be recalculated on insert. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct. However, it is likely to be less efficient than just rebuilding the entire set, since `insert` and `remove` are _both_ O(log n) complexity.

Comment: Yes you right. It would be nice if collections had method `update_all()` which would take closure to update each element individually. That would be handy. Could you update your answer to include code for replacing elements? Because I was looking for the ways it could be done. Anyway I accept your answer.

Comment: @my- Using a `HashSet` instead, you can `drain` the collection and rebuild with modified values: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab03d053e58dd9ad8afc07e10c2859ef . But `drain` is not available (yet) for  `BTreeSet`.

Comment: Worth noting that mutating an element in a set or a key in a map doesn't _always_ invalidate the collection. If the part you mutate isn't used for the collection's calculations, then it's fine. This isn't usually the case, however.

Comment: @Shepmaster True, but doing this can become a ticking time-bomb because the type checker can't protect you from future code changes that break your assumptions. I would just never suggest doing it except in extremely rare circumstances. If someone did this in my codebase, I'd want to see (1) an extremely good justification, (2) extensive documentation of the implications and (3) automated tests that the assumed invariants are preserved.

Answer (score 2):

`BTreeSet` doesn't implement [`impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a mut BTreeSet<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) (that would break the tree).

You can only do this with types that implement `IntoIterator` with `mut` like `impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a mut Vec<T>`, [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e64b54962878e492f70746c8803e272).

Comment: Is here a way to edit code to make it work with BTreeSet?  I need uniqueness and order. Say somehow to change getter or change how update code works?? I have feeling it should be possible. What I thing is probably something like this: get collection reference > create new `TreeSet` from it > assign newly created `TreeSet` to reference. But how to do it in Rust.. I don't have much experience.

Comment: Or maybe even: get collection (borrow it) > take (remove from collection) each element > update it > insert back to collection updated element. In that case tree wont be broken.

Comment: @my- see other answer but if you need to mutate all your elements frequently, maybe you are not using the good collection. But without more context I can't advise you more.

Comment: I doubt updates would be frequent. Well in worst case scenario - yes, but I think it is only on the edge cases. I'm doing coding challenge in some site.

Answer (score 2):

### For sets that are not a field of a struct

Even `std::mem::replace` is not required.

```rust
data_in_some_strct = data_in_some_strct
    .into_iter()
    .map(|mut p| p.offset(&Pos::of(1, 0)))
    .inspect(|p| println!("{:?}", *p))
    .collect();
```

#### Explanation

1. We essentially build an iterator for moving out the `BTreeSet`’s contents.
2. Then we call `.map()` over the elements and call the required methods.

   It should be noted that it works here because `.offset(...)` returns `Self`. If the method does not return `Self`, you can simply write:

   ```
   // ...
   .map(|mut p| {
        p.offset(&Pos::of(1, 0));
        p
   })
   // ...
   ```
3. At last, we use `.collect()` to construct a `BTreeSet` with all newly "updated" values.

### For sets that are a field of a struct

Let's assume that the field's name is `data_in_some_strct` of some given struct `Foobar`.

```rust
struct Foobar {
    data_in_some_strct: BTreeSet<Pos>,
}
```

Let's say hypothetically we also have method called `Foobar::update()` that updates the values in the set.

```
impl Foobar {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To update the set from within, we'd have to use `std::mem::take()`.

```rust
fn update(&mut self) {
    self.data_in_some_strct = std::mem::take(&mut self.data_in_some_strct)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|mut p| p.offset(&Pos::of(1, 0)))
        .inspect(|p| println!("{:?}", *p))
        .collect();
}
```

#### Explanation

The key takeaway here is `std::mem::take()`'s usage. It's doc says:

> [It] Replaces `dest` with the default value of `T`, returning the previous `dest` value.

This essentially means that the destination value (here `data_in_some_strct`) is replaced with a default value (which happens to be an empty set for `BTreeSet`), and the original value is returned.

We then perform the same operations on the value returned by `take()` as in the previous explanation above.

As stated above, `collect()` builds a new `BTreeSet` for us by inferring its type from `self.data_in_some_strct`. We then move the newly created `BTreeSet` to `self.data_in_some_strct`.

**Note**: You can replace `*p` with `p`.

---

This is especially valuable and noteworthy for people who will use (or are
already using) `Rc<RefCell<T>>` or its thread safe variant.

Instead of using `map()` to mutate the values in-place, thus putting the code at risk of logic error, one should follow the steps above.